# How to convert json key with an underscore to a new object in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

If I have some json such like..

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "dob": "20010101",
  "tel_home": "01785200200",
  "tel_work": "01785300300",
  "tel_mobile": "07123456789",
  . . .
}
```

How can I convert it to (whenever an underscore is shown)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "dob": "20010101",
  "tel": {
    "home": "01785200200",
    "work": "01785300300",
    "mobile": "07123412345"
    }
  . . .
}
```

The properties can change so I cannot deserialise to an object.
Many thanks for any help

-Jenny

Comment: You can deserialize to Newtonsoft's [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and dynamically build new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse your JSON into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), save all properties, starting from `tel_` value. Then remove them from original `JObject`, create a new one with updated properties names and finally add the created object to original one

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var properties = json.Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("tel_"))
    .ToList();
properties.ForEach(p => json.Remove(p.Name));

var newObject = new JObject(properties.Select(p => new JProperty(p.Name.Replace("tel_", string.Empty), p.Value)));
json.Add("tel", newObject);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

It gives you the following result

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "dob": "20010101",
  "tel": {
    "home": "01785200200",
    "work": "01785300300",
    "mobile": "07123456789"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Newtonsoft you can declare custom serialzers:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm

This will allow you to inspect one token at a time and place it any object or variable you want.